# need help solving a quartic equation

Tags: quartics

The question I am asking is to solve the equation $x^4-4x-1=0$,
I need an exact answer. What I have done was found out that it equals $(x^2+1)^2 - 2(x+1)^2 =0$.
Anybody help me, please?

Comment: Hint: you now have an expression of the form x^2 - y^2 = 0. How does that simplify?

Comment: If you edit your post and surround your math with dollar signs, like this: \$x^4-4x-1=0\$, it will better fit site standards for writing math.

Comment: @JuliaHayward So basically it's a difference of squares now.

Comment: Yes, what can we say about the relation between $x$ and $y$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So you know

$$\begin{align}
x^4-4x-1&=(x^2+1)^2-2(x+1)^2\\
&=(x^2+1)^2-[\sqrt2(x+1)]^2.
\end{align}$$

Factorise this difference of two squares to get two quadratic factors, hence the four roots.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Use $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$ to get $2$ quadratic *equations*$(=0)$.